Set Up for Testing Apple Books
Screenshot of what I'm seeing
I am new to XCode and the XCTest framework. I am trying to write a few tests on Apple Books. I am writing the set-up to actually open the app, but I'm having trouble. On Xcode I'm trying to test on an iPhone 15. I am using a MacBook Pro.
I'm not sure why it's not able to launch Books correctly, but it is launching the 'Hello World' that was included in the 'starter code' for a new project in Xcode.
I wrote an initial few lines (below) in the Swift file under my UI Test folder about what I think should open the App, using the bundle identifier.
Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!
P.S. in terms of writing the test, is there a cheat sheet to what commands there are available for specific features of the book such as turning a page? How about something simple like browsing through different tabs on the page?

import XCTest
let books = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.iBooksX")

final class Apple_Books_TestUITests: XCTestCase {
    
    func launchApp() {
        books.launch()
    }
    

}
    



No.. see  - https://super-tester.medium.com/ios-how-to-automate-tests-for-apps-without-having-access-to-development-source-code-a35824abd5e3
